# How to create views with multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view

I have two tables as

```
CREATE TABLE table1(id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(10));
CREATE TABLE table2(id NUMBER, dept VARCHAR2(4));
```

Now, I want to create a view containing id and name from the table table1 and dept from the table table2. I have a query like

```
CREATE VIEW table_view 
AS SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t2.dept 
FROM table1 t1 full outer join table2 t1 
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

But I get the error: ORA-00904: "T2"."ID": invalid identifier.
Help me clear the error. Thanks.

Comment: you have wrong alias at table2 t1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave both tables the same alias `outer join table2 t1` should be `outer join table2 t2`

```
CREATE VIEW table_view 
AS SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t2.dept 
FROM table1 t1 
   full outer join table2 t2 --<< here 
                ON t1.id = t2.id;
```